# Azure Databricks write JSON Data to Parquet file throws error: TypeError: Can not infer schema for type

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark-sql, parquet, databricks

I am downloading in an Microsoft Azure Databrics Notebook with Python from an WebService following data:

```
{
    "Customers" : 
   [
        {
            "CustomID" : "106219-891457",
            "CustomerDateTime" : "0000105910",
            "purchasedItems" : 
            [
                {
                  "itemId" : "tBNU5awl2Yac",
                  "state" : "OBSOLETE",
                  "materialNumber" : "0000werqw4603100",
                  "materialName" : "Licasdr",
                  "quantity" : 1,
                  "orderType" : "STANDARD",
                  "Ingredients" : 
                  [
                    {
                        "ingredientId" : "146a00dd036__7e06",
                        "ingedrientDesc" : "bla"
                    },
                    {
                        "ingredientId" : "146a234d036__7e06",
                        "ingedrientDesc" : "bla2"
                    }
                  ],
                  "lastModificationDate" : "2014-09-30T10:13:46.8Z"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

This works fine and i get the result shown in my Notebook as above.

I need to convert/write this data to a Parquet file. I am trying to do this with the following line

```
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection('companyhost.com')
conn.request("POST", "/public/api/customers/purchases/findByDate", request, headers)
response = conn.getresponse()
data = response.read()
print(data)
conn.close()

from pyspark.sql.types import *

df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.show()

df.write.format('parquet').save(mypath)
```

But in the line

> df = spark.createDataFrame(data)

i am receving the following error message:

> TypeError: Can not infer schema for type: type <'str'>

What is happening here? What am i doing wrong?

Comment: It seems you need to convert response to json object first

Comment: @Ritesh: And how to do this?

Comment: As I am not from python background, so can't exactly know the library name. Though you can use some json library to convert string to json object. If that doesn't work, then try to create custom schema for your json. Also go through https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/read-json.html link

Answer (score 0):

To create a dataframe from a json file you need to do the following:

```
df = spark.read.json(data)
```

or

```
df = spark.read.format('json').load(data)
```